# Simplest Way to Iterate Through Multiple Arrays of Structs?

Tags: arrays, swift

Looking to increment through multiple arrays of structs using one of their variables for number of loops per.  Thanks!

```
struct Example {
    var partOne: Int
    var partTwo: Int
    var partThree: Int
}

var one = Example(partOne: 10, partTwo: 11, partThree: 12)
var two = Example(partOne: 10, partTwo: 11, partThree: 12)

var arrayOfExamples = [one, two]

for i in 0...arrayOfExamples[0].partThree {
    print(i)
}

//once i = 12, then

for i in 0...arrayOfExamples[1].partThree {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use nested loops with the outer loop iterating over the items of the `arrayOfExamples`:

```
for item in arrayOfExamples {
    for i in 0...item.partThree {
        print(i)
    }
}
```

---

By using `KeyPath`s, you can write a function that iterates over the values with the property specified by the caller:

```
func iterateOverKeyPath(array: [Example], keyPath: KeyPath<Example, Int>) {
    for item in array {
        for i in 0...item[keyPath: keyPath] {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}

// iterate using partThree property
iterateOverKeyPath(array: arrayOfExamples, keyPath: \Example.partThree)

// now do the same for partTwo
iterateOverKeyPath(array: arrayOfExamples, keyPath: \Example.partTwo)
```

---

And there's nothing really special about the `Example` `struct`, so we could make this generic to work for any type:

```
func iterateOverKeyPath<T>(array: [T], keyPath: KeyPath<T, Int>) {
    for item in array {
        for i in 0...item[keyPath: keyPath] {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did I answer you question, or did you have follow up clarifications?